# Can single delayed job worker start the next job before the ongoing job ends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have implemented API rate limiting in my application for calling 3rd party API service which limits the number of requests made to service in a specified time interval.

I went through delayed job documentation and could not find the information i was looking for.

My case is;

If there is a really short amount of time, let's say 5 seconds, between 2 delayed jobs, what will the worker do?

Will it wait for the first job to finish even though the second job execution time has arrived, or will it start the job on the specified time?

If the latter, It will break my rate limiting implementation since API is only letting me 60 requests per minute and and both jobs will just limit themselves to 60 requests per minute and in total both jobs will try to send around 120 requests in a minute.

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the numbers of DelayedJob workers that are available. Because a free worker will pick a job and process it as soon as its `run_at` time has come.

If you need to ensure that only on job runs at a time, I see two simple options:

1. limit your number of workers to `1`. Or
2. enqueue the next job as the last step of processing.

That might look like this:

```
class Job
  def process
    # code for the job ... 

    # enqueue the next job to run in 5 seconds
    Job.delay(run_at: 5.seconds.from_now).process
  end
end
```

A third option that is a bit more complex, plays with [named queues](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#named-queues). When you enqueue this kind of jobs into a special named queue, then you can use that special queue to calculate the time for the next job. Instead of just enqueue a job like this:

```
Job.delay.process
```

Check if a job already exists, like this:

```
queue_name = 'one_at_a_time'
latest_job = Delayed::Job.where(queue: queue_name).order(:run_at).last
run_at     = latest_job ? latest_job.run_at + 5.seconds : Time.current
Job.delay(queue: queue_name, run_at: run_at).process
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I already decreased the workers to 1 and if i understad it correctly, this will be enough right? The worker will be busy working on the first job and will only start working on the second one when the first one finishes?

"enqueue the next job as the last step of processing." can you elaborate on that little bit? In my applications, users are the ones that schedule the jobs, so there is no way to know when they will plan their jobs.

Comment: Yes, decrease workers to 1 would ensure that there is only one job running at a time. I didn't know that users schedule jobs in your app. Under this circumstances the second version does not work. But then there might be another option. Will update my answer in a few minutes...

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed explanation, I see what you did there as a third option and that can work but it will need a little different implementation. Because the last job is not always the one that can conflict with the one that we are about to create, right? Users can schedule a job for next month and can also schedule it for next day. I kind of need to check he previous and next 10 seconds for example in order to see if there is any potential conflicts. But for now i will go with the single worker i think.

Answer (score 0):

And another option is to run one worker instance per queue:

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job --queue=tracking start`

or

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job --queues=mailers,tasks start`

[Documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs)

Comment: other than that for After job completed than only it runs another ?

Comment: @VishwasNahar Yea. If you have one worker per queue. Also make sure that every dj worker has a queue specified because workers started without specifying a queue will run jobs from **any** queue.

Comment: sure but in my case i have 100's places where delayed job call i cant assign one worker for this job only